# What is the MaxEnvelopeSizekb

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have been googling around to find out what the MaxEnvelopeSizekb is.

It seems to be the source of another problem, I cannot tell what it is or what it is for.

Windows server 2016

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = true
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
        MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647
```